# Python convert xml to json a bytes-like object is required

Tags: python, json, xml

I have xml file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns="http://cnig.gouv.fr/pcrs" gml:id="PlanCorpsRueSimplifie.1" version="2.0">
    <gml:boundedBy>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <featureMember>
        <EmpriseEchangePCRS gml:id="EmpriseEchangePCRS.12189894">
            <datePublication>2020-05-13</datePublication>
            <type>Cellules</type>
            <geometrie>
                <gml:MultiSurface gml:id="EmpriseEchangePCRS.12189894-0" srsName="EPSG:3944" srsDimension="3">
                    <gml:surfaceMember>
                        <gml:Surface gml:id="EmpriseEchangePCRS.12189894-1">
                            <gml:patches>
                            </gml:patches>
                        </gml:Surface>
```

I wouldike to transform this file into json file.
I tried this but I have always the same error :

```
import xmltodict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(open('JeuxTestv2.gml').read())

print(xmltodict.parse(root)['Main'])
```

ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xmltodict.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(xmltodict.parse(root)['Main'])
  File "C:\Users\xmltodict.py", line 327, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'
```

Comment: I think you should feed the XML string (or the open file object) to `xmltodict.parse` directly, without the need to use `ElementTree`. E.g. `print(xmltodict.parse(open('JeuxTestv2.gml')))`.

Comment: @myrmica thank you it works !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I am using Python 3.7.6**

When I tried, ET.fromstring() will parse the XML that is already represented in string format.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
xml_doc_path = os.path.abspath(r"C:\dir1\path\to\file\example.xml")
root = et.fromstring(xml_doc_path)
print(root)
```

this example will show the following ERROR

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2
```

I used ET.**tostring()** to generate a string representation of the XML data, which can be used as a valid argument for xmltodict.parse(). [Click](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) here for the ET.**tostring()** documentation.

The below code will parse an XML file and also generates the JSON file. I used **my own** XML example. Make sure all the XML tags are closed properly.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element1 attribute1 = 'first attribute'>
    </element1>
    <element2 attribute1 = 'second attribute'>
        some data
    </element2>
</root>
```

**PYTHON CODE:**

```
import os
import xmltodict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import json
xml_doc_path = os.path.abspath(r"C:\directory\path\to\file\example.xml")

xml_tree = et.parse(xml_doc_path)

root = xml_tree.getroot()
#set encoding to and method proper
to_string  = et.tostring(root, encoding='UTF-8', method='xml')

xml_to_dict = xmltodict.parse(to_string)

with open("json_data.json", "w",) as json_file:
    json.dump(xml_to_dict, json_file, indent = 2)
```

**OUTPUT:**
The above code will create the following JSON file:

```
{
  "root": {
    "element1": {
      "@attribute1": "first attribute"
    },
    "element2": {
      "@attribute1": "second attribute",
      "#text": "some data"
    }
  }
}
```